# Using IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>> in parallel

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task

Can someone please direct me how to use `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<double>>` in parallel / task efficiently. Appreciate your help.

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> Execute(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> lists)
{
          //Looking to process each enumerable item in separate thread/task
);
```

Comment: Have you tried first looking at AsParallel ()?

Comment: can you post some code that you have tried?

Comment: I get that AsParallel() for single level IEnumerable. Looking answer for nested IEnumerables.

Comment: No real difference, really - you can parallelize the outer sequence, then parallelize the inner ones? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Its a complex data structure. As per 'Microsoft All Rules' from code analysis you should not embed lists but create new class in such case.